# How do I attach data in POST request - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, post

How do I attach multiple data with a POST request in swift.
As attached screen shot from postman it is working fine when select the x-`www-form-urlencoded` option
How do I attach 5 data with the body like `'x-www-form-urlencoded'` option.

Here the code,

```
var request = URLRequest(url: urlString)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        var urlComponents = URLComponents()
        urlComponents.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: “***”, value: “***”),
            URLQueryItem(name: "***", value: "***"),
            URLQueryItem(name: "***", value: "***"),
            URLQueryItem(name: "***", value: "***"),
            URLQueryItem(name: "***", value: "***"),
        ]
        request.httpBody = urlComponents.percentEncodedQuery?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let loadDataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let _ =  error{
                completion(false,error)
            }
            else if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse{
                if response.statusCode != 200{
                    completion(false,error)
                }
                else{
                    do{
                        if let parsedData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []){
                            let ff = parsedData as? Dictionary<String,Any>
                            print(ff)
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }//let loadDataTask
        loadDataTask.resume()
    }
```

[image]

Comment: String data only

Comment: **Simplest solution: ** Click on `Code` in postman (attached screen).
Select Swift in the modal appears after clicking Code. You will get the code you need, remove the unnecessary postman parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SWIFT 4:**

```
let url = URL(string: “url”);
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
urlRequest.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded",forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = “paramerter1=value1&parameter2=value2”
urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
```

Comment: This answer doesn't encode the data properly as far as I can see

Answer (score 5):

One easy way to create the http body is to use `URLComponents` like this:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: yourUrl)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

var urlComponents = URLComponents()
urlComponents.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "your_first_parameter", value: "someValue"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "your_second_parameter", value: "someValue"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "your_third_parameter", value: "someValue")
]
request.httpBody = urlComponents.percentEncodedQuery?.data(using: .utf8)
```

Comment: I have updated the code. it is not working. I got response code 400.

Comment: Did you set the query items correctly? Because otherwise there is nothing different to your accepted solution. Except this solution is more robust regarding the query encoding.